# What's a good tool/addin for Windows to copy a file's path?

Tags: windows-7

I often find that I need the full path of file, often when that file is on the desktop/start menu (i.e., not viewing within [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer)).

<sub>(There's a related question, but it's asking for a solution in Windows Explorer. I want solutions that'll work everywhere.)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The freeware shell extension [ClipPath](http://download.cnet.com/ClipPath/3000-2094_4-10050927.html) can do this. Simply right click the file and select **Clip Path**:

[image]

> **ClipPath (Version 2.1)**
>
> As a Programmer, we are often required
>   to set the path or classpath
>   Environment variables. But Windows
>   Operating does not allow us to copy
>   the full path of a file or a
>   folder,say, c:\temp\try.java to
>   clipboard so that we can paste the
>   same anywhere we require.
>
> Clip Path utility tries to solve these
>   problems. It is a windows Shell
>   Extension Program. Once installed, you
>   can copy full path of a file or folder
>   to clipboard.
>
> Support for copying path of multiple
>   files or folders is also provided.
>
> Support for UNIX style path (/) is
>   also provided.

In Windows Vista and 7, this is not needed. You can simply hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, right-click the file and select **Copy as path**:

[image]

I am not sure if this works in the Start menu though. Maybe someone can clarify.

Comment: Great answer!   I *thought* I'd heard that this was built-into Win7.

Comment: Yep, just tricky to find :)

Comment: Interesting, because the numerous utilities I see only copy Windows style path. Only Synesis' extension can copy in Unix style (useful to paste in strings of most languages), but it doesn't work in Win7. And I guess that Win7's trick doesn't copy in Unix style either. Alas, the site you link to doesn't respond right now.

Comment: Actually, all of these SHIFT tricks do not work, Clippath was smart enough to remove the Mapped drive letter of mapped network shares and copy the entire network path. Very useful for emailing links to items on file shares where others would not have the same drive mapped... Clippath also had options to copy outlook compatible links as well as forward or backward slashes...

Answer (score 1):

It's sucks having to press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key every time that you want to copy a path on Windows 7 (I need to do this a lot at my job). I use [ClipboardPath](http://ptf.com/download/clipboardpath/97981/) instead. It works for Windows 7 and other versions.

There's this other too, but I didn't try it: http://www.mydigitallife.info/copy-path-information-for-multiple-files-to-clipboard-with-copy-path/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own shell extension to do this: http://yoy.be/allsorts

It can also translate selected paths to URL's using the values in a registry key, copy the content of text files, toggle the read-only flag, and update the modified date.